# how to completely remove .wsp solution

Tags: 2010, solution-package

how to remove a .wsp solution 
i try from central admin>system settings>manage farm solution 
selected a solution and selected Retracting  still this status shown Restract.

how to completely remove this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are two ways to completely remove it.

**Use Central admin.**

- go to central admin >System Settings -> Manage farm solutions.
- On this Page, click on the solution which you want to remove.
- 1st retract it,then remove it.

**Use PowerShell**

```
[Uninstall-SPSolution][1] –Identity SPSoltion.wsp   

[Remove-SPSolution][1] –Identity SPSolution.wsp
```

At the end, if you solution has a timer job, then you need to restart the timer job as well.

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove a solution:

1. Deactivate all features brought by this solution, in all site collections/sites it may be activated in.
2. From CA, choose Retract from the WSP details page. If it is a per-Web app WSP (as opposed to a globally-deployed WSP), choose "All content Web applications".
3. Wait (refresh the page) till it's marked "not deployed"
4. Choose Delete from the WSP details page.

If you're stuck at step #3 with a status frozen on "Retracting", you can try the following in a SharePoint PowerShell console (on all servers of the farm):

```
Net Stop SPAdminV4
Start-SPAdminJob
Net Start SPAdminV4
```